# Parse a value between two single quotes in a text column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to query the results of `xp_readerrorlog`, which I am loading into a temp table. I need to query the `LogText` column,  specifically looking to parse a value between two single quotes.

Two example records:

| LogText |
| --- |
| Login succeeded for user 'Frank'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. |
| Login succeeded for user 'Domain\User_999'. Connection made using Integrated authentication. |

I am already filtering data in the temp table to only include rows starting with `Login succeeded`.

In the query, I want the results to be:

|  |
| --- |
| Frank |
| Domain\User_999 |

How can I do this?

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING(LogText, CHARINDEX('\'', LogText) + 1, CHARINDEX('\'', LogText, CHARINDEX('\'', LogText) + 1) - CHARINDEX('\'', LogText) - 1) AS Value
FROM #TempTable

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here yet to answer the question. I suspect there are other kinds of messages in the column as well, and it's not clear what you want to do in that situation: filter out the rows, show NULL or empty strings, show the original text, etc. It may also be possible different kinds of messages also have two single quotes, and it's not clear how strict you want to be matching `Login succeeded` messages.

Comment: I only want the data between the single quotes, the provided query has a syntax error. I am already filtering out the data to only contain the rows that start with Login succeeded.

Comment: So is `Login succeeded for user '` a static string that is always the same? i.e. you can just start reading at character 27 and stop when you see the first quote?

Comment: Hi Martin, yes I would like to give it a try.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(LogText, 27, CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), LogText, 27) - 27)` would work for that case then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems the prefix is always fixed here (`Login succeeded for user '`) you can just use.

```
 SUBSTRING(LogText, 27, CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), LogText, 27) - 27)
```

For a slightly more generic version replace the hardcoded `27` with

```
(CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), LogText) + 1)
```